# How to resolve UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Following [this example](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#axes-coordinates):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
for i, label in enumerate(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i+1)
    ax.text(0.05, 0.95, label, transform=ax.transAxes,
      fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

plt.show()
```

I get this output:

[image]

Why are my labels normal weight, while the documentation shows this should create bold letters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`?

I also get this warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1228
UserWarning)
UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=italic:variant=normal:weight=bold:stretch=normal:size=x-small. Returning C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\Vera.ttf
```

### OP Resolution

- From a [deleted answer posted by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18814074/7758804) on `Sep 15, 2013`

  - *Ok, it was a problem with the installation of `matplotlib`*

Comment: As per the OPs statement, I'm voting to close this question as not reproducible.

Answer (score 14):

Try using `weight` instead of `fontweight`.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe try using this -

```
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 16
plt.rcParams['axes.labelweight'] = 'bold'
```

Do this at a global level in your program.

Answer (score 5):

The example from your question works on my machine. Hence you definately have a library problem. Have you considered using latex to make bold text? Here an example

[image]

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1)
ax0, ax1, ax2 = axs

ax0.text(0.05, 0.95, 'example from question',
        transform=ax0.transAxes, fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')
ax1.text(0.05, 0.8, 'you can try \\textbf{this} using \\LaTeX', usetex=True,
        transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=16, va='top')
ax2.text(0.05, 0.95,
         'or $\\bf{this}$ (latex math mode with things like '
         '$x_\mathrm{test}^2$)',
        transform=ax2.transAxes, fontsize=10, va='top')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still having the issue.  I tried your code in Anaconda/Spyder, Python 2.7.  The plots appear with Bold labels (A,B,C,D).  I agree the issue is probably with the library.  Try replacing / updating font_manager.py or confirming font files are present:

Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent quite a few hours today on that. Here`s the solution that helped me:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()
```

With this, the `font_manager` could be upgraded easily.